# SSH timeout: ClientAliveInterval & ClientAliveCountMax VS ServerAliveInterval & ServerAliveCountMax

Tags: ssh

In order to prevent ssh session time out there appears to be two mechanism available. One configured client side (ServerAliveInterval & ServerAliveCountMax) and the other server side (ClientAliveInterval & ClientAliveCountMax).

The way I see it, I should set this up server side. I'ts less work, affects every client and has the added bonus of releasing ports (on the server) used on reverse tunnels (which stay stuck in "listening" for a while when a connection drops).

But is there anything else to it? Are they both equally reliable for keeping an ssh connection alive? Is there any point in using both?

Thanks for sharing your expertise.

Fred.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after searching around for an answer to this, everything suggest that the only difference is which side of the connection is doing the monitoring.

The tests I have done confirm this and appear to accomplish exactly the same thing.

Comment: What kind of tests did you run? I'm facing a similar issue where I need my pi to keep it's uplink alive and if it fails/disconnects a node script waits 30 seconds and tries to establish a new connection. The problem I'm facing is sometimes, for unknown reasons (so far), it just doesn't want to reconnect. I'll try to look up the error codes. So I don't know if its the pi or the ssh server it's trying to reconnect too. Wondering if the server is booting the pi for some reason on reconnect.

Comment: Oh yeah, and I think the `ServerAliveInterval` & `ServerAliveCountMax` is set on the client side. So the opposite. [Similar Question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-do-the-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-conf)

Comment: ^_- isn't that what I wrote? I have a similar setup. I have a bunch of PIs connecting to our server. Difference may be that I am using autossh to launch the ssh connection from the PIs at boot via /etc/network/interfaces just add this line at the very bottom `post-up autossh -M 0 -f -N -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 tunnels_go_here user@host_or_ip -p your_port`

Comment: I also have both ClientAlive... params set in sshd_conf on the server which means I am keeping alive from both sides, not sure its required. Only had a problem once were the reverse tunnels dropped but not the regular tunel and for some reason autossh didnt detect it. Hope that helps.